# Error - Drop column of a partitioned table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

How do I drop a column of a partiotioned table in Hive?
I have an external table with 4 columns, for example:

column_A

column_B

column_C

dt_test - partition

I have to drop the column_C, so, I'm trying the follow command:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE REPLACE COLUMNS(column_A string, column_B string, dt_test timestamp);
```

The follow error occurs:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 40000 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.DDLTask. Partition column name dt_test conflicts with table columns.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can drop column_c  by the follow command:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE REPLACE COLUMNS(column_A string, column_B string);
```

not having the partition column:  **dt_test timestamp**